# How do I get created and the last modified time of each table for a given database in Redshift?

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, information-schema

I am trying to get "created" and the "last modified time" of each table for a given database in Redshift.

I did check INFORMATION_SCHEMA and STL views but did not find answer. STL views can help but as per AWS docs, it maintains data only for 2-5 days so it will not give complete picture of all available tables.

Need assistance on this.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep some catalog data around for historical purposes I'd recommend that you define a process that stores information from the needed tables / views every 12 or 24 hours.

Define a schema for saving this information and write a process to update these "stashed away" versions of the required information.  Then define some views that span these historical tables and the up to date catalog data so you only need to ever look at one place for the needed table info.

You then get to define when data will age out of these tables, if ever.  These are now part of your data system and under your control.  Catalog data can get large which is why is ages out.  Saving only that catalog data that is important to you will keep the space required under control.

Comment: Thanks Bill.. Going forward we will have some mechanism to capture these details and will do consider your suggestions but right now any way I can get this info?

Comment: To get table modification dates that extend back further than the catalog schema clean-up interval (varies by cluster activity) you will need to perform some activity to capture it (save catalog tables, store modification dates in your ETL etc.).  As for creation dates, the catalog view pg_class_info (and pg_class) has creation date (relcreationtime) for each relation in the database.  This was introduced some time back so may not have all table info if you cluster is more than a few years old.